# PyDevD is preventing pytest to correctly generate coverage

Tags: python, pytest, pydev, pytest-cov

I am dealing with an issue of generation coverage which does not work as expected. Finally I found out it's somehow connected to [pydevd](https://pypi.org/project/pydevd/) (PyDev debugger) package.

To reproduce my issue you can use following repo: [cov-project](https://github.com/sxooler/cov-project)

There are only two files. One in `my_package` with

```py
import pydevd  # Just for the purpose to show the problem

def sum(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

def mult(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2
```

And the test file `test_math.py` in tests:

```py
from my_package.math import sum, mult

def test_sum():
    assert sum(1, 2) == 3

def test_mult():
    assert mult(2, 3) == 6
```

When I remove `import pydevd` from the first file and run `python -m pytest --cov=my_package tests` I get this output:

```
Name                     Stmts   Miss  Cover
--------------------------------------------
my_package/__init__.py       0      0   100%
my_package/math.py           4      0   100%
--------------------------------------------
TOTAL                        4      0   100%
```

Yes, 100% coverage as expected. But when I run the same and keeping importing `pydevd` I get:

```
Name                     Stmts   Miss  Cover
--------------------------------------------
my_package/__init__.py       0      0   100%
my_package/math.py           5      4    20%
--------------------------------------------
TOTAL                        5      4    20%
```

The testing is completely same, the only change is this additional import. Of course, in this setup `pydevd` is unused and I can simply remove it. But I use it in my proprietary code so I wanted to show the simplest way how to reproduce my error since I cannot generate appropriate coverage report when using `pydevd`. I could change it to local import as I do not use it in my tests, then it would work, but I'm trying to understand what is happening here and why would `pydevd` prevent coverage from successful report generation.

**Tested**:

- with python 3.8 and 3.9
- with pydevd 2.2.0 and 2.3.0
- pytest 6.2.2
- pytest-cov 2.11.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was really a bug in `pydevd`.

I've fixed it in https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger/commit/be32cd821f2574566385deeec23081365bf16722

You can apply the same fix to your local version in the meanwhile.

To find out the file for the fix you can do:

```
import pydevd
from _pydevd_bundle import pydevd_constants
print(pydevd_constants.__file__)
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick fix! This will be part of the next release, right? If so, do you have any expectation when it might be released? Since the last one happened just a few days ago, I guess it will not be this month..

Comment: Actually, I plan to release soon as I want to change the comment blocks again on PyDev, so, it should be soon (1-2 weeks probably).

Comment: Hi, do you have any updates regarding the release?
The bug was fixed on Feb 27, but the latest PyPI version, 2.3.0, was released Feb 21.
Thank you.

Comment: It's already released, use version 2.4.1, since there was some bug in 2.4.0